React state always back to initial value or it always create new instance of class
What Is wrong With My code cause form state always back to initial value or it always create new instance of "forms" class

interface loginComponentProps {}

const LoginComponent: FC<loginComponentProps> = () => {
 
 const [loggedIn, setloggedIn] = useState(false);
 const [form, setFormInstance] = useState(new forms({ userName: '', password: '' } as LoginDto,
 [
 { Key: 'userName', validationFunc: Validations.isRequird },
 { Key: 'password', validationFunc: Validations.isRequird },
 ]))
..........
 return (
 <ImageBackground/>  
     ..........
 </ImageBackground>
 );
};



It's difficult to see without a more of your code shown (how is LoginComponent consumed, how are the login form acting, etc), but the short version is your state hooks are being reset every render, which is why form keeps being reset.
Either provide some persistence for the current state of form, falling back to a new forms(...) if no data is persisted, or ensure that your hooks to handle form management correctly use things like useCallback with the correct dependency arrays.

Your codes seem correct. Check your form component and make sure onChange methods of your form children components work correctly.
